# Date different in field calculator using python method

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, field-calculator, python-script-tool, python-parser

I would like to calculate date different between two fields of date format.
The idea is to know if Field_1 is greater than Field_2.

My calculate code is something like this:

```
def date(f1,f2):
  if f1 > f2:
    return'yes'
  else:
    return'no'
```

> date( !Field_1!, !Field_2! )

The format of Field_1 and Field_2 is :

> %m/%d/%Y

The script is run but the result is not as I expected.
As you can see below, the result is not different each other.
[image]

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you are having trouble with--are you receiving an error? Or is your data just not what you expected? Screen shots of errors or examples of results returned vs results expected help.

Comment: ("NO","YES") [!DATE_NOW! > !DATE_OLD!]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution in VBS

```
dim output
if [DATE_NOW]  > [DATE_OLD] then
  output = "YES"
else
  output = "NO"
end if

ACTION = 

output
```

[image]

The solution above worked for me...

Here is the python solution,  i believe this should work, I am not at my pc to test at the moment.

```
"YES" if !REPORTED_DATE! > !CLOSE_DATE! else "NO"
```

[image]

Comment: It's works for me too, thanks ed.hankins. But, is there any way by using python?Because I want to combine this script with another script in python.

Comment: Try this then,  just plug this right into ACTION = "YES" if !REPORTED_DATE! > !CLOSE_DATE! else "NO"

Comment: I got a little problem here. I want to use "and operator" on that script, but it's error. The script is like IF [PROPINSI]="Aceh" AND [DATE_NOW] >[DATE_OLD] then output = "YES" ELSEIF [PROPINSI]="Aceh" AND [KOTA] NOT IN ("Langsa","Banda Aceh") then output = "NO" endif. I use pre logic. Sorry I cannot use my computer. Is there any way?

Comment: I found the problem is on "not in" operator. Then I use <> operator, but I think it's not good enough